# Would you recommend getting the DAR (discount argentina) card in Buenos Aires / Salta?

Tags: sightseeing, museums, argentina, buenos-aires

I came across the DAR, Discount Argentina, card ([discountargentina.com](http://www.discountargentina.com/)) while looking up information about museums in Buenos Aires. I was wondering, if anyone has had experience with this card, have you found it worthwhile? Is there a preferable place to get the card? Any other tips?

Answer (score 5):

This is a very personal question, because it depends on what you want to do during your stay in Argentina. Personally I believe it's not worth the price you pay because prices in Argentina are really low. For example, you can go to dinner for 5 USD (good dinner, not fast food), so a 20% discount in a restaurant that costs 30 USD isn't worth it unless you specifically want to go to this restaurant. Or for instance, you can go to see a free tango show (you only pay for the drinks) unless you pay an entrance and an expensive drink.

So my advice is, make a plan based around what you really want to do and check how much you would save with this card. Also you can ask here for budget or even free alternatives.

Comment: Thanks @hippietrail, my english is not very good :) but I'm learning. I've changed the "conflictive" word ;)